# Problema ao startar gulp serve

Tags: angularjs, node.js, gulp, bower

Boa tarde,

Estou criando um portal em AngularJS e Node.

Após instalar na pasta de trabalho o npm `npm install` e o bower `bower install`

O tutorial pede para que seja feito o comando `gulp serve`, porém esta apresentando o seguinte retorno:

> [13:50:21] Error: Missing binding
>   C:\Users\ms74902\Desktop\Portal_Fuse\node_modu
>   les\node-sass\vendor\win32-x64-51\binding.node Node Sass could not
>   find a binding for your current environment: Windows 64-bit with
>   Node.js 7.x
>
> Found bindings for the following environments:
>     - Windows 64-bit with Node.js 7.x
>
> This usually happens because your environment has changed since
>   running `npm install`. Run `npm rebuild node-sass` to build the
>   binding for your current environment.

Obs: Já executei o comando `npm rebuild node-sass` mas sem sucesso, node, e todos modulos estão atualizados.

> bower@1.8.0
>   gulp@3.9.1
>   Node v7.1.0

Comment: Tenta dar um npm install no gulp novamente.

Comment: Tente utilizar alguma versão 6.* do nodejs.
Pode ser alguma incompatibilidade do node-sass + NODEJS 7.* com Windows-64bits

Comment: Se por acaso funcionar regredindo a versão, poste como resposta. Os problemas com node-sass são recorrentes na WEB.

Answer (score 0):

Seu cache NPM pode estar corrompido.

Tente

`npm cache clean`

seguido de

`npm rebuild node-sass`

Comment: Boa tarde OnoSendai, apresentou o mesmo erro.